# Elasticsearch performance impact on choosing mapping structure for index

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, memory

I am receiving data in a format like,

```
   {
     name:"index_name",
     status: "good",
     datapoints: [{
       paramType: "ABC",
       batch: [{
         time:"timestamp1<epoch in sec>",
         value: "123"
       },{
         time:"timestamp2<epoch in sec>",
         value: "123"
       }]
     },
     {
       paramType: "XYZ",
       batch: [{
         time:"timestamp1<epoch in sec>",
         value: "123"
       },{
         time:"timestamp2<epoch in sec>",
         value: "124"
       }]
     }]

   }
```

I would like to store the data into elasticsearch in such a way that I can query based on a `timerange`, `status` or `paramType`.

As mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/nested.html), I can define `datapoints` or `batch` as a nested data type which will allow to index object inside the array.

Another way, I can possibly think is by dividing the structure into separate documents. e.g.

```
{
name : "index_name",
status: "good",
paramType:"ABC",
time:"timestamp<epoch in sec>",
value: "123"
}
```

which one will be the most efficient way?

if I choose the 2nd way, I know there may be ~1000 elements in the `batch` array and 10-15 `paramsType` array, which means ~15k documents will be generated and 15k*5 fields (= 75K) key values pair will be repeated in the index?

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) this explains about the advantage and disadvantage of using nested but no performance related stats provided. in my case, there won't be any update in the inner object. So not sure which one will be better. Also, I have two nested objects so I would like to know how can I query if I use nested for getting data between a timerange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat structure will perform better than nested. Nested queries are slower compared to term queries ; Also while indexing - internally a single nested document is represented as bunch of documents ; just that they are indexed in same block .

As long as your requirements are met - second option works better.